# C++ Inheriting Protected Members

Tags: c++, inheritance

Okay, for some reason inheritance is not working the way I thought it would work, and it's vexing me strongly. Let's say I have two classes - `BaseMessage` and `DerivedMessage`. Same namespace. I define them in `messages.hpp` as such:

```
class BaseMessage
{
public:
    BaseMessage();
    virtual ~BaseMessage();

protected:
    BString<2> _messageType;
};

class DerivedMessage : public BaseMessage
{
public:
    DerivedMessage();
    virtual ~DerivedMessage();

protected:
    BString<2> _informationType;
};
```

The idea is, I have multiple derived messages, all with unique fields (which I haven't included here), but they ALL have a message type. So I figured I'll stick messageType into the parent class and have all of its children inherit it. Except I am obviously doing it wrong, because if we look at `messages.cpp`:

```
BaseMessage::BaseMessage() { }

BaseMessage::~BaseMessage() { }

/* #TODO: Implement helper functions */

/* *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***  */

DerivedMessage::DerivedMessage()
: _messageType("SS")
{

}

DerivedMessage::~DerivedMessage() { }
```

the compiler throws a fit about "class ‘full::namespace::DerivedMessage’ does not have any field named ‘_messageType’"

The only other thread I found somewhat useful was one where the problem was in trying to access the parent's protected attribute from the child - but I don't think that's my case, I am trying to set `DerivedMessage`'s `_messageType`, the only thing I need the parent `BaseMessage` is to declare it.

Or am I going about it poorly? I just thought, maybe I need to work with virtual attributes instead of protected ones?

Comment: I could be wrong, because I don't know what you intent to do with your messages, but you might want to avoid using message types and let the message dispatch via a virtual function, so the receiver of the message only needs to call that function instead of checking the type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`_messageType`, being a member of `BaseMessage` subobject of `DerivedMessage`, needs to be initialized by `BaseMessage`'s constructor:

```
class BaseMessage
{
public:
    BaseMessage();
    BaseMessage(const char* c) : _messageType(c) {}   // <--- here
    virtual ~BaseMessage();

protected:
    BString<2> _messageType;
};
```

Then, in derived class' constructor, write a forwarding call like this:

```
DerivedMessage::DerivedMessage()
: BaseMessage("SS")
{  }
```

Answer (score 4):

A member can only be initialised by the class that contains it, not a derived class. So initialise it in the base class constructor:

```
explicit BaseMessage(BString<2> type) : _messageType(type) {}
```

and pass this through from the derived class:

```
DerivedMessage() : BaseMessage("SS") {}
```